# Exec regex inside dowhile loop

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get access to a few substrings inside the a stylesheet's `:root` selector.

So far, I've gotten the CSS, and I've successfully composed a regex that does the matching ok.

But in order to access the capture group, I've realised through some research that I need to do it iteratively in order to get all matches of a longer string:

```js
const rootColors = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].cssText;
const colorRegex = /--color-([\w]+-?[\w]+)/gi

const matches = []

do {
    const match = colorRegex.exec(rootColors)
    if (match && match[1]) matches.push(match[1])
    matches.sort()
} while (colorRegex.exec(rootColors));

console.log(matches) // ["primary", "primary-dark", "secondary-light", "tertiary", "tertiary-dark"]
```

However, the loop fails to get all nine matches that I expect. The generated CSS looks as so:

```css
:root {
  --color-primary: #FF6342;
  --color-primary-light: #fd9a77;
  --color-primary-dark: #ff4d0f;
  --color-secondary: #645DD7;
  --color-secondary-light: #9488df;
  --color-secondary-dark: #4730d1;
  --color-tertiary: #7180AC;
  --color-tertiary-light: #949bbc;
  --color-tertiary-dark: #535e97;
}
```

I was sort of expecting the `matches` array to contain all nine CSS variables with the prefix `--color-` omitted.

Does the dowhile loop come with some caveats that I'm unaware of?

Comment: You call `exec` twice but get the results once

Comment: Why do you sort the array on every round of your loop? Do it only once _after_ the loop.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew oooh makes sense